# Cannot use apt-get anymore because of one specific package

Tags: package-management, apt

No matter what type of apt-get I run (install, update, ...) I always get:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libgdata-google1.2-1' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.

dpkg: warning: files list file for package `libntlm0' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 354644 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libntlm0 1.1-1 (using .../libntlm0_1.1-1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libntlm0 ...
```

At this point apt-get hang. Does somebody know a way to fix this?

Some days ago a line in source.list was removed (Google Chrome).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One command which will possibly fix the problem is

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

Other options which can be combined with this are `--ignore-missing` or `--fix-missing`

Also try this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

For any help on commands and options, please see `man dpkg` and `man apt-get`.

A very detailed answer with many more options  to come out of deadlock can be found [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Specific to Libre Office, I faced a problem and what helped me was individual purging of packages using `dpkg --purge` as described [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+question/189183)

Comment: "sudo apt-get --fix-broken install" fixed my problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors that can lead to a file list going missing (it is just a file in /var/lib/dpkg/info), but the most common is a problem in the file system itself. The easiest way to correct that is by rebooting with the command `shutdown -F -r now`, and subsequently watching the show.

The automated check will correct any errors it can without destroying data (for example, it will clean up files that have been deleted, but where the space has not been freed yet), but if it needs a decision, it will refuse and ask for the administrator to correct the problem manually, which is sort of an art in itself and more complex than I can explain here (it may be a sign of a problem with the harddisk, identifying this takes some experience though).

The dpkg error can be corrected by reinstalling the package, ideally in the exact same version (the files list is just a list of all files that were inside the package when it was unpacked, so using the same or a sufficiently similar version of the package will give the same list).

That dpkg hangs at this point is definitely wrong and also screams "filesystem issue" to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the sources.list is empty (because you expect it to be?) check the file sources.list with

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If you see url's with your distro name at the end you will probably have the right sources.list content. The sources.list file contains the repositories you connect to with apt. Usually you leave this default unless you want to install newer versions or specific software that is unavailable in the default repositories but is maintained by a 3rd party.